# Sed alternative for search and replace on very long lines

Tags: sed

I have files that were generated by a program that did not put newlines at the end of records. I want to put newlines between the records, and I can do so with a simple sed script:

```
sed -e 's/}{/}\n{/g'
```

The problem is that the input files are multiple gigabytes in size, and therefore the input lines to sed are multiple GBs in length. sed tries to hold a line in memory, which doesn't work in this case. I tried the `--unbuffered` option, but that just seemed to make it slower and did not allow it to finish correctly.

Comment: Would it be possible to upload an example input file somewhere for us to try some ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could first use `tr` to translate `}` into `\n` and then use `sed` to add a `}` at the end of each line? Like this : `tr '}' '\n' < your_file.txt| sed 's/$/}/'`

Comment: Does adding a newline at the end of the file help at all? Like: `printf "\n" >> file`

Comment: @Ketan, I assume writing a file with 78 garbage characters following by `}{` repeated until it's several gigabytes long would suffice.

Comment: @nanny - good point - but where do you get 78? If the records are already blocked then `dd if=file cbs=80 conv=unblock` would do it - but it's rarely that simple.

Comment: @mikeserv 80 characters is a common max width for text files. (78 garbage chars plus two: `}{` equals 80). Seems like a reasonable line length to use for testing.

Comment: @nanny - gotcha - just checking in case i'd missed it. Thanks much.

Comment: This is old, but for the future, please see my [answer regarding bbe, a binary sed-like utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581890/317657).  It really is IMO the simplest approach.  You literally do this: `bbe -e 's/}{/}\n{/'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use another tool that lets you set the input record separator. For example

- Perl

  ```
  perl -pe 'BEGIN{ $/="}{" } s/}{/}\n{/g' file
  ```

  The special variable `$/` is the input record separator. Setting it to `}{` defines lines as ending in `}{`. That way you can achieve what you want without reading the entire thing into memory.
- mawk or gawk

  ```
  awk -v RS="}{" -vORS= 'NR > 1 {print "}\n{"}; {print}' file
  ```

  This is the same idea. `RS="}{"` sets the record separator to `}{` and then you print `}`, a newline, `{` (except for the first record) and the current record.

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -i~ -e ' $/ = \1024;
              while (<>) {
                  print "\n" if $closing and /^{/;
                  undef $closing;
                  s/}{/}\n{/g;
                  print;
                  $closing = 1 if /}$/;
              } ' input1 input2
```

Setting `$/` to `\1024` will read the file in chunks of 1024 bytes. The `$closing` variable handles the case when a chunk ends in `}` and the next one starts with `{`.

Comment: +1, probably the best solution ; the other perl/awk solutions work fine too but what if the first record separator occurs after about 17GB worth of chars ?

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
{ <infile tr \} \\n;echo {; } | paste -d'}\n' - /dev/null >outfile
```

It's probably the most efficient solution.

That puts a `{}` to protect any possible trailing data. With one more `tr` process you can swap that around and do a blank line at the head of the first `{` field. Like...

```
tr {} '}\n'| paste -d{\\0 /dev/null - | tr {}\\n \\n{}
```

So the first, with don's example data, does:

```
printf '{one}{two}{three}{four}' |
{ tr \} \\n; echo {; }           |
paste -d'}\n' - /dev/null
{one}
{two}
{three}
{four}
{}
```

...and the second one does...

```
printf '{one}{two}{three}{four}'      |
tr {} '}\n'| paste -d{\\0 /dev/null - |
tr {}\\n \\n{}
#leading blank
{one}
{two}
{three}
{four}
```

There is no trailing newline for the second example - though there is one for the first.

Answer (score 1):

## A Binary `sed`-like utility called `bbe`

I find it easiest to stay with sed-like syntax in this case.

I ***much*** prefer using the `bbe` utility (available via your {uni,linu}x's package installation, e.q. `apt-get`).  Or [here](https://github.com/hdorio/bbe) if you're one of the git crowd, though I haven't personally vetted that particular link.

### 1. It supports the `s/before/after/` idiom

It's a "Binary Block Editor", which supports sed-like (among other) operations.  This includes the super common `s/before/after/` substitution idiom that you need.  Note, because there are no lines per se from `bbe`'s point of view, there is no "global g" at the end of the command.

As a quick test (note the required `-e`):

```
$ echo hello | bbe -e 's/l/(replaced)/'
```

produces:

```
he(replaced)(replaced)o
```

### 2. In your specific case of `}{` to `}\n{` conversion

So if we had a massive file filled with a million numbers in (say) the format `{1}{2}{3}`...`{1000000}` with no carriage returns, we could exchange the `}{` with `}\n{` easily, and have all the numbers one per line.

This would be with this `bbe` command:

```
bbe -e 's/}{/}\n{/'
```

As tested in this zsh loop, which we grab just the tail of:

```
$ for ((num=0; num<1000000; num++)) do; echo -n "{$num}"; done | bbe -e 's/}{/}\n{/' | tail
```

Which would produce this:

```
{999990}
{999991}
{999992}
{999993}
{999994}
{999995}
{999996}
{999997}
{999998}
{999999}
```

(without a trailing carriage return of course.)